# How to create a QR code Scanner which automatically fetches UPI IDs like Paytm, WhatsApp etc.?

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code, firebase-mlkit, image-scanner

I want to create my own QR Scanner which automatically detects or fetches UPI info, particularly UPI ID from any QR if present. The mobile_scanner package in flutter gets the code from any QR but from the long string i can't fetch just the UPI.

eg: From a complex QR it reads.

**000201010211021644038462029515060415522024062029515061661000306202951570825HDFC00000015020000391584826490010A0000005240131shradhatravel.62029515@hdfcbank27420010A0000005240124STQD571562516354474448275204599953033565802IN5914SHRADHA TRAVEL6008VARANASI610622100262400524STQD571562516354474448270708620295156304f4ea.**

I want to automatically fetch "shradhatravel.62029515@hdfcbank" like in Paytm and other apps.

Comment: You may want to use the issue reporting page to ask the owner of the package: https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/mobile_scanner/issues

Comment: Have you tried parsing the string? any QR reader will return the string value of the QR code and you need to parse it to get the values you want.

Comment: Its already a string. What do i parse it into?